# Update page data after pop Navigation Updated #5

Tags: flutter, dart, navigation, reload

I have page Navigate to second page with variable (dID) with await to return same  value if it has been changed ,at the second page if i did't do anything the value must return without any changes ,if i changed slider the value of (dID) must be increase by (1) ,but when i Navigate.pop the return value is same without increasing.

### New update : After many test i did the problem is in the second page ,when i change the slider value i  call a function to get the new value (newSavedDayId) ,and it is get it correctly but just inside the function ,after the slider change and get the new value ,it is returned to null :

```
newSavedDayId  = Instance of 'Future<dynamic>'
```

second page which return value :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';
import '../classes/viewdigree.dart';
import 'package:youtube_player_flutter/youtube_player_flutter.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
class Days extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DaysState createState() => _DaysState();
}
TextEditingController insertedDegree = TextEditingController();
class _DaysState extends State<Days> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List digrees = [];
    var widthView = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    Map rdata = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments;
    var did = int.parse(rdata['dayId'].toString());
    var u_id = rdata['userID'];
    var m_id = rdata['courseId'];
    var lang = rdata['lang'];
    int w_id;
    var newSavedDayId = rdata['savedDayID']; ----// received value
    var username;
    if (did <= 6) {
      w_id = 1;
    } else if (did <= 12) {
      w_id = 2;
    } else if (did <= 18) {
      w_id = 3;
    } else {
      w_id = 4;
    }
    Future<List> fetchDigrees() async {
      var url =
          'https://srdtraining.com/api/controller/activities/activiy_list.php?d_id=$did&m_id=$m_id&u_id=$u_id';
      var response = await http.get(url);
      var data = jsonDecode(response.body);
      print(data);
      for (var x in data) {
        Digree newdigree = Digree(
            x['index'],
            x['title_k'],
            x['title_a'],
            x['aya'],
            x['link'],
            x['activity_k'],
            x['activity_a'],
            x['act_id'],
            x['mydigree']);
        digrees.add(newdigree);
      }
      return digrees;
    }
// Insert Func
    send_degree(uId, actId, degree, w_id, did, m_id) async {
      var sendData = {
        'u_id': uId.toString(),
        'act_id': actId.toString(),
        'digree': degree.toString(),
        'm_id': m_id.toString(),
        'd_id': did.toString(),
        'w_id': w_id.toString()
      };
      var url = 'https://srdtraining.com/api/controller/data/changedata.php';
      var response = await http.post(url, body: sendData);
    }
// End of Insert Func
//get user status .................. // this is the function to get new value
    void getUserStatus() async {
      SharedPreferences preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
      setState(() {
        username = preferences.getString('username');
      });
      var url =
          "http://srdtraining.com/api/controller/users/status_user.php?username=$username";
      var response = await http.get(url);
      var data = jsonDecode(response.body);
      setState(() {
        newSavedDayId = int.parse(data['d_id']); ----// Set New value by getting it from API after increasing by server.
      });

      print('newSavedDayId = $newSavedDayId');----// here it is print new value with increasing correctly
    }
// End get user
    return FutureBuilder(
        future: fetchDigrees(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.data == null) {
            return Scaffold(
              body: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    image: DecorationImage(
                        image: AssetImage('./assets/images/background.png'),
                        fit: BoxFit.cover)),
                child: Center(
                  child: Text("Loading"),
                ),
              ),
            );
          } else {
            YoutubePlayerController _controller = YoutubePlayerController(
                initialVideoId: snapshot.data[0].link,
                flags: YoutubePlayerFlags(
                  autoPlay: false,
                  mute: false,
                ));
            return Scaffold(
              appBar: AppBar(
                leading: IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.pop(context, newSavedDayId);
                    }),
                backgroundColor: Colors.pink[900],
                title: Text(
                  'ژیان و قورئان',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 32),
                ),
                centerTitle: true,
              ),
              body: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    image: DecorationImage(
                        image: AssetImage('./assets/images/background.png'),
                        fit: BoxFit.cover)),
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                child: ListView(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(25, 20, 25, 20),
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text(
                        lang == 'k'
                            ? snapshot.data[0].title_k
                            : snapshot.data[0].title_a,
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 32, color: Colors.white)),
                    //for top margin
                    SizedBox(height: 20.0),
                    // dexription
                    Container(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
                      width: widthView,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
                          color: const Color.fromRGBO(180, 80, 80, 0.3)),
                      child: Text(snapshot.data[0].aya,
                          textAlign: TextAlign.justify,
                          textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontFamily: 'Hafs',
                              fontSize: 26,
                              color: Colors.greenAccent[100])),
                    ),

                    // now populating your ListView for `Directionality`
                    Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        // Start activities
                        Column(
                            children: snapshot.data.map<Widget>((item) {
                          double _value =
                              double.parse(item.mydigree.toString());

                          return Directionality(
                            textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
                            child: Column(
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Container(
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                                      border: Border.all(
                                          width: 2, color: Colors.white),
                                      color:
                                          Color.fromRGBO(230, 200, 200, 0.2)),
                                  width: widthView,
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(25),
                                  margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 25, 0, 25),
                                  child: Column(
                                    children: <Widget>[
                                      Text(
                                        lang == 'k'
                                            ? item.activity_k
                                            : item.activity_a,
                                        textAlign: TextAlign.justify,
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                            fontSize: 28, color: Colors.white),
                                      ),
                                      SizedBox(
                                        height: 15,
                                      ),
                                      Container(
                                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                            boxShadow: [
                                              BoxShadow(
                                                color: Colors.yellow[200]
                                                    .withOpacity(0.2),
                                                spreadRadius: 2,
                                                blurRadius: 20,
                                              )
                                            ],
                                            borderRadius:
                                                BorderRadius.circular(15),
                                            color:
                                                Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, 0.4)),
                                        width: widthView,
                                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                                        child: Slider(
                                            max: 100,
                                            min: 0,
                                            divisions: 100,
                                            value: _value,
                                            label: _value.round().toString(),
                                            onChanged: (val) {
                                              send_degree(u_id, item.act_id,
                                                  val, w_id, did, m_id);
                                            },
                                            onChangeEnd: (val) {
                                              setState(() {
                                                _value = val;
                                              });
                                              getUserStatus(); /// when i print the value here it is give me null
                                            }),
                                      ),
                                      SizedBox(
                                        height: 10,
                                      ),
                                      Text('$_value',
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                              fontSize: 26,
                                              color: Colors.white))
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                )
                              ],
                            ),
                          );
                        }).toList()),
                        // End activities
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 20,
                        ),
                        Text('خەلەکا ئەڤرو',
                            textAlign: TextAlign.right,
                            style:
                                TextStyle(fontSize: 26, color: Colors.yellow)),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 20,
                        ),
                        YoutubePlayer(
                          controller: _controller,
                          showVideoProgressIndicator: true,
                          progressIndicatorColor: Colors.blueAccent,
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            );
          }
        });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can usef **ValueChanged onChanged** and do a callback to the page you want to update ,
you can  passe the onChanged funtion on the parametre ,
when you change your value use : onChanged()
than in the page you want to see the update on call your function with set state ,

Comment: Thanks Sister ,the value of level changed in third screen ,and i return it's value on pop Navigator  as shown on codes above ,but i can't receive it

Comment: i couldn't follow how you're doing it exactly , but refering to your  #update , since you have the right value and just don't know how to pass it , try to use static variable and call it in your main class

Comment: Can you please write code to more understand ,thanks sis

Comment: put : static your_var; in the class that change the value , than call it : YourClass.your_var

Comment: ex ;class MyClass extends StatefulWidget { static int you_var;
  @override
  //code ; // init your static var
}  , than you call  MyClass.your_var

Comment: Thank you sister ,I have changed the question more clearly ,Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by merging two function in one :

```
Future<List> fetchDigrees() async {
      var url =
          'https://srdtraining.com/api/controller/activities/activiy_list.php?d_id=$did&m_id=$m_id&u_id=$u_id';
      var response = await http.get(url);
      var data = jsonDecode(response.body);
      print(data);
      for (var x in data) {
        Digree newdigree = Digree(
            x['index'],
            x['title_k'],
            x['title_a'],
            x['aya'],
            x['link'],
            x['activity_k'],
            x['activity_a'],
            x['act_id'],
            x['mydigree']);
        digrees.add(newdigree);
      }
      return digrees;
    }
   void getUserStatus() async {
  SharedPreferences preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  setState(() {
    username = preferences.getString('username');
  });
  var url =
      "http://srdtraining.com/api/controller/users/status_user.php?username=$username";
  var response = await http.get(url);
  var data = jsonDecode(response.body);
  setState(() {
    newSavedDayId = int.parse(data['d_id']); ----// Set New value by getting it from API after increasing by server.
  });
```

and they now like this and worked correctly :

```
Future<List> fetchDigrees() async {
  SharedPreferences preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  username = preferences.getString('username');
  var url1 =
      "http://srdtraining.com/api/controller/users/status_user.php?username=$username";
  var response1 = await http.get(url1);
  var data1 = jsonDecode(response1.body);
  newSavedDayId = int.parse(data1['d_id']);
  print('newSavedDayId before retrun = $newSavedDayId');
  var url =
      'https://srdtraining.com/api/controller/activities/activiy_list.php?d_id=$did&m_id=$m_id&u_id=$u_id';
  var response = await http.get(url);
  var data = jsonDecode(response.body);
  print(data);
  for (var x in data) {
    Digree newdigree = Digree(
        x['index'],
        x['title_k'],
        x['title_a'],
        x['aya'],
        x['link'],
        x['activity_k'],
        x['activity_a'],
        x['act_id'],
        x['mydigree']);
    digrees.add(newdigree);
  }
  return digrees;
}
```